# Dynamic CRM - insert external hyperlink with dynamic parameters in Email workflow

Tags: email, hyperlink, dynamics-crm, crm, microsoft-dynamics

I have a Workflow in CRM 2016 on premise that sends an email to a customer when an order is created.   The email contains a URL link to external website used for scheduling.  The problem is that the hyperlink in the email doesn't fill the parameters we are using from the CRM entities.

I tried several ways to do this.  the first way was using the Insert Hyperlink when creating the email through the workflow. this creates the following tags:

`<hyperlink><name>Pro Services Online Scheduling Portal</name><value>https://secure.website.com/ProServices?name={Ship To Contact(Order (Order))}&email={Email(Ship To Account (Account))}&OrderID={Order ID(Order (Order))}&Company={Customer(Order (Order))}&skip=0</value></hyperlink>`

This correctly adds the hyperlink into the email but the actual link looks exactly as it does in value tag without the CRM values.
I tried just adding the link as plain text like so:

```
https://secure.website.com/ProServices?name={Ship To Contact(Order (Order))}&email={Email(Ship To Account (Account))}&OrderID={Order ID(Order (Order))}&Company={Customer(Order (Order))}&skip=0
```

This displays the correct URL with the correct CRM values like: https://secure.website.com/ProServices?name=JonDoe&email=jdoe@email.com&OrderID=ORD-123456&Company=FakeCompany&skip=0
However, the URL itself is still missing the values so if the customer clicks on the link, the incorrect parameters will be sent.  It does work if the customer were to copy and paste the link text instead of clicking the URL but most customers would rather click the link.

I even tried used an HTML anchor tag but that also didnt work.

Has anyone else encountered this problem?

Any help would be appreciated.

Here's some blog posts that helped but still looking for answers.

http://dotnetskills-reenapatel.blogspot.com/2014/02/how-to-form-dynamic-hyperlink-url-for.html

http://www.magnetismsolutions.com/blog/paulnieuwelaar/2012/06/25/dynamic_clickable_email_hyperlink_dynamics_crm_2011_workflow

Comment: Can you try this?

`<a href='https://secure.website.com/ProServices?name={Ship To Contact(Order (Order))}&email={Email(Ship To Account (Account))}&OrderID={Order ID(Order (Order))}&Company={Customer(Order (Order))}&skip=0'>Pro Services Online Scheduling Portal</a>`

Comment: Tried that but it didnt work.  Same problem.  Ended up creating a custom workflow step to add the hyperlink

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We ended up creating a custom workflow activity to add the hyperlink using SparkleXRM

Answer (score 0):

If you want to use hyperlink then you have to do something similiar to what CRM does for field Record URL(Dynamic).
You can create a new field on the entity say 'EntityName Hyperlink'. Then use plugins to set this value to the desired link on create event.
You can then use this field to create your hyperlink. We do something similair for our case entity we have field Case Hyperlink which i set on create event.
Then we insert it on outgoing emails like this

```
<hyperlink><name>Hyperlink</name><value>{Case Hyperlink(Case)}</value></hyperlink>
```

Comment: I was trying to avoid this route.  I was hoping there was another way then creating an entity field and populating via a plugin.  It seems like overkill for something as simple as a hyperlink.